# Firebase: Registering users based on their phone numbers added by admin

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Newbie here. What I am trying to do is allow users to register via their phone number, only when their phone numbers have been added earlier by the admin. Any help or link to resources would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: There is no way to prevent a user from authenticating themselves with Firebase Authentication. But you can prevent them from using other resources. For more info on how to do that for the Firebase Database, see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security

Comment: Thanks for the resource. From yours and Alex's answer, I think that I didnt think this idea through. Having mobile numbers verified before hand does lead to issues and shouldnt be done. Probably I should just send an sms verification (via third party perhaps) as soon as the admin enters a mobile number and ask the user to login using that code / password and later change their password. [edited: for readability]

Answer (score 1):

Basically via your admin account, you would need to add the "good" numbers inside a node let's call it "white_list" and its reference whiteListRef.

Then you would need the two essential Firebase methods to register a user via his phone number, the first one is :

```
PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phone_number) { }
```

It will send a verification code to the user.

Then you need to add this method :

```
Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { }
```

credential is created using the verificationID you got from the first method, and the verification code that your user received to his phone number if his number was correct :

```
 let credential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(
        withVerificationID: verificationID,
        verificationCode: verificationCode)
```

In your case, you would need to check that the phone number your user typed in is among the white list (that your admin added into the white_list node). Depending on your database structure, for example, you could use a method like this one :

```
func checkNumberEligibility(_ phoneNumber: String, completion: @escaping(Bool) -> Void) {

       whiteListRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

         guard let numberEligibility = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "eligibility").value as? String else { return }

        if numberEligibility == "good" {
            completion(true)
        } else {
            completion(false)
        }

    })
```

**Finally, you would have something like this :**

```
 func registerPhoneNumber(_ phoneNumber: String, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {

        PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber) { [weak self] (verificationID, error) in

            guard error == nil else {
                return
            }

         self?.checkNumberEligibility(phoneNumber) { (isNumberOkay) in

            guard isNumberOkay else {
                return
            }

            UserDefaults.standard.set(verificationID, forKey: "authVerificationID")

        }

      }

  }


    func verifyCode(_ verificationCode: String, completion: @escaping() -> Void) {

        guard let verificationID = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "authVerificationID") else {
            return
        }

        let credential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(
            withVerificationID: verificationID,
            verificationCode: verificationCode)

        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential, completion: { (user, error) in

            guard error == nil else {
                return
            }

            completion()

        })

    }
```

This would work, however, to do it this way, it does mean that you would need to give the access via the database rules to that white list node to any person (that is to mean, even non users of your app) which might expose you to security issues. So you might consider that before implementing this system.

Just let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: You are right. I didnt think of the security issues. The mobile numbers would stand exposed. Thanks for the answer. I learnt from it.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could help